# Importing PHP Namespace To Extend A Class In That Namespace

Tags: php, class, namespaces

This post is due to some difficulty I am having extending a class defined in a first namespace from a second namespace. Based on this post :

[PHP how to import all classes from another namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121682/php-how-to-import-all-classes-from-another-namespace)

I tried this :

File NameSpace1 :

```
<?php
namespace FirstNS;

class baseObject
{
    public $baseVar = 1;

public function baseFun() {}
}

?>
```

File NameSpace2 :

```
<?php
namespace SecondNS;

use FirstNS;

class extendedObject extends FirstNS\baseObject {
    public $extendedVar = 1;

    public function extendedFun() {

    }
}

?>
```

However `$this` in `extendedFun` can only access `$extendedVar` and `extendedFun`, not `$baseVar` and `baseFun`. I have also tried `use FirstNS as ClassFromFirstNS;` and `class extendedObject extends ClassFromFirstNS` however `$baseVar` and `baseFun` are still not accessible via `$this`. The information at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php also did not seem to directly address this case.

Comment: How are you instantiating the object? `$object = new baseObject()` or `$object = new extendedObject()`?

Comment: @Digital Precision, this is merely in the class extension definition. If this were all in one file like so :

    <?php

    class baseObject
    {
        public $baseVar = 1;

        public function baseFun() {}
    }

    class extendedObject extends baseObject {
        public $extendedVar = 1;

        public function extendedFun() {

        }
    }

    ?>

$baseVar and baseFun would be accessible from within extendedFun. This is to try to learn what namespace declarations are required to make $baseVar and baseFun accessible when accessing the namespace from a different file.

Comment: Namespaces are more or less unrelated to visiblity. They just play a role for a classname and allow you to prefix all class and function names within each namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```
// File1.php
namespace FirstNS;

class baseObject
{
     public $baseVar = 1;

     public function baseFun() {}
}

// File2.php
namespace SecondNS;

include 'File1.php';

use FirstNS;

class extendedObject extends FirstNS\baseObject {

    public $extendedVar = 2;

    public function extendedFun()
    {
        var_dump($this->baseVar); // Outputs 1
        var_dump($this->extendedVar); // Outputs 2    
    }
}

// File3.php
include 'File2.php';

$object = new SecondNS\extendedObject();

$object->extendedFun();
```

Comment: I've tried to include the original file, and I tried your code for file1 and file2 right now, @Digital Precision, however the baseClass members are not visible from inside the extendedObject definition.

Comment: @LiteratiInsolitus: Updated code, check the `extendedFun()` method. Worked in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problems to get your code to work, it's not clear from your question where you've got a problem:

```
namespace FirstNS
{
    class baseObject
    {
        public $baseVar = 1;    
        public function baseFun() {}
    }
}

namespace SecondNS
{
    use FirstNS;
    class extendedObject extends FirstNS\baseObject
    {
        public $extendedVar = 1;
        public function extendedFun()
        {
            echo $this->extendedVar, "\n"; # works
            $this->baseFun(); # works
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    $obj = new extendedObject();
    echo $obj->baseVar, "\n"; # works
    $obj->extendedFun();
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zl5Vj3) - Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Your solution works because it's all in the same file, the OP states it's across 2 files.

Comment: Was this all in one file; in the second file I also tried : namespace SecondNS; include 'NameSpace1.php'; use FirstNS; as per http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php however the members of the base class still do not show up.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, hate when that happens.

Comment: @LiteratiInsolitus Two file example (eval is like include): http://codepad.viper-7.com/FlzgKO - you're just looking at the wrong points. Simplify your example and start w/o namespaces because actually namespaces aren't related to this. Whatever you try, you should also add your full code to the question. I don't see anywhere in your question where you access something nor are you giving any error messages. But those are absolutely important.