# Laravel 5.6: How to use all models contained in one folder

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5.6

I have a folder named "Models" located at app/models in my laravel project directory. 
I want to use all models by a single line of code in controller, instead of using each one like:

```
use App/Models/User;
use App/Models/Roles;
```

Comment: bad practices 
what's the reason you want do this ?

Comment: you can use namespace like normal class but this usage not same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP how to import all classes from another namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121682/php-how-to-import-all-classes-from-another-namespace)

Comment: Have you tried this: `use App\Models;` then in your code simple do , `Models\ User::get()`. Sincerely, I don't see the benefit of doing this. You can look into "Group use declarations" section at http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: use App/Models/{User,Roles}

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/models/' . $className . '.php';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this folder in your `composer.json` file.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories",
        "app/Models"
    ]
}
```

then run `composer update`