# Using a composer script with a hyphen in the name?

Tags: php, composer-php

I a'm trying to use the following script from Github: https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver

Installing with composer in "/mnt/hgfs/" was easy, but loading the class in a php file seems impossible

As you can see, there is a hyphen in the name, and i can't seem to load the class in any way. I have googled for a lot and tried many things, but same problem, either i get:

Trying to use the hyphen in namespace and use i get

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting '{' in
>   /mnt/hgfs/test.php on line 3

Replacing hyphen with underscore, or just removing it i get:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   'php_webdriver\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities' not found in
>   /mnt/hgfs/test.php:10

This is how my code looks (/mnt/hgfs/test.php):

```
namespace php_webdriver\WebDriver;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use php_webdriver\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use php_webdriver\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver;
use php_webdriver\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use php_webdriver\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::htmlUnitWithJS();
{
    $options = new ChromeOptions();
    $options->addArguments(array(
        '--disable-extensions',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--headless',
        '--no-proxy-server'
    ));
    $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
    $capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
    $capabilities->setPlatform("Linux");
}
$driver_spec = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 600000, 600000);
```

How should I load this class?

Comment: Hyphens are invalid namespace characters. Their [example](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/blob/community/example.php) doesn't seem to use a path with a hyphen in. Are you able to just delete and re-install it to a directory/namespace structure without?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here:

```
namespace php_webdriver\WebDriver;
```

You shouldn't be trying to add your code to the webdriver namespace. For a test script you don't need your own namespace. You can probably delete this line.

As for:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use php_webdriver\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use php_webdriver\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver;
use php_webdriver\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use php_webdriver\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
```

I get the impression you're not 100% familiar with how PSR-4 / autoloading works. The namespace is mapped to a code directory by `autoload.php`, and the two don't necessarily have to have the same naming structure.

Take a look at the [`composer.json` in the webdriver project](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/blob/community/composer.json), and pay attention to the `PSR-4` section.

`"Facebook\\WebDriver\\": "lib/"` tells you that anything in the `lib` directory is to be considered as being in the `Facebook\WebDriver` namespace.

Try

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
```

Comment: Thank you, now the above code works. But now in production i need this namespace as i get: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WebDriverBy' not found in /mnt/hgfs/test.php:861 and proberly more if i set this in use (I was using Facebook/Webdriver before, but composer complaint about beeing abanded and I should use php-webdriver instead) Any suggestions?

Comment: The `WebDriverBy` class exists (https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/blob/community/lib/WebDriverBy.php), but you don't seem to have imported it at the top of your test script. Add `use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;` at the top of your `test.php`

Comment: Thank you again, but now the next one is "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WebDriverExpectedCondition' not found in /mnt/hgfs/test.php:893" thats why i need the namespace. Before they changed their name from facebook to php-webdriver i only sat Namespace and those 4 use'es from question and it found those classes itself

Comment: If you want to import all classes from a given namespace you can [just import the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121929/1081756). If you want to specify, for example, _some_ classes within a namespace that contains many with a single import statement (eg you need classes A, B, H, and H, but not C, D, E, or F), you can do `use Whatever\Namespace\{ClassA, ClassB, ClassG, ClassH};`

Comment: I just didn't know how to import the namespace when there was a hyphen in the name, but with your help i tried using "Facebook\WebDriver" as namespace and BANG no missing classes anymore, thank you so much for all your help and time!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)